# Drawable folders structure and files

Tags: android

So I am creating the icons for my action bar and Im having a very stupid problem, I suppose, but I cant get over it.

I have the following folders:

drawable
drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi

and in the last 4 folders I have different versions of my icons with different sizes.

Problem comes when I define the icons in the action_bar.xml file:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/abSettings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_device_access_storage"
    android:title="@string/abSettings"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

I get an error saying it cant find this file in "drawable" which is true.

So which version of the images should I put in the drawable folder?

Comment: Have you checked that there's a `ic_action_device_access_storage.png` inside at least one of your `drawable` folders?

Comment: there are 4 different sized versions of this image in all folders but the one named just "drawable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get an error saying it cant find this file in "drawable" which is true

You are not specifying a folder. You are specifying a type of resource (here, `drawable`). If you look one line below, you do not have a `string` folder, either -- that's a reference to a `string` resource.

> So which version of the images should I put in the drawable folder?

None of them. Presumably, you have a typo somewhere. If you are using Eclipse, switch to the graphical editor and try choosing a resource for it in there.

`res/drawable/` is usually reserved for XML drawables (e.g., `LevelListDrawable`, `StateListDrawable`), as they do not have an intrinsic density.